# Matlab support for groovy

Tags: matlab, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the groovy distribution and I would like to communicate with Matlab through the ROS I/O package. On the Matlab page it is stated that hydro is necessary. Does anyone have experience if groovy works as well ?

Fabian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200679/matlab-support-for-groovy/) by [psfa_fz](https://answers.ros.org/users/20415/psfa_fz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found someone doing exactly this - it seems to work

http://www.brendanandrade.com/2014/02/12/ros-i0-getting-started-with-mathworks-new-ros-package-for-matlab-p1/

---

Originally posted by [psfa_fz](https://answers.ros.org/users/20415/psfa_fz/) with karma: 36 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2015-01-09**:
Feel free to mark this as the answer.